# Reduplicated usage of "my": what does this mean?

Tags: informal-language, lyrics, repetition, interjections

Popular music is a good entry into language learning and many usages naturally reflect prose (non-lyric)  usages. David Bowie sings "my my" in the song *[Beauty and the Beast](http://www.metrolyrics.com/beauty-and-the-beast-lyrics-david-bowie.html)* and  Ariana Grande sings "my my my my my..." in the song called *Adore* by Cashmere Cat, featuring Ariana Grande.

This got me thinking about prose uses of **my** as an exclamation. As in

> My, it's a beautiful day.

But what about repeated use of *my*, as in

> My my, look who's here.

What does repeated use of *my* mean? Is it different from single use?

Does this come from *oh my god* or *oh my?*

Answer (score 2):

*My my* is, according to  [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/my-oh-my), a variation  of *my oh my*.

They are both interjections expressing surprise, pleasure, admiration, even sarcasm...

*Oxford English Dictionary* says that **my** (not repeated) is used vocatively

> in exclamatory phrases, as my eye!, my God!, my gracious!, my oath!, my stars!, my word!, etc

and that it, and *oh, my!*, is used when

> Expressing surprise or admiration.
>
> 1875 ‘Mark Twain’ in Atlantic Monthly Aug. 195/2 ***My***, what a race I've had!

and the same for

> reduplicated forms, as *my, my!* and *my oh my!*, etc.
>
> 1986 *New Yorker* 26 May 77/2 ***My my*** and here I am out where I can't even get a case of Scotch to celebrate.

The reduplicated form shows that the *sound* of words is important in conveying meaning. And reduplicated prose forms carry a quality that is not far from song-like usage, or singing itself.

So this very basic meaning of *my* and *my my* is the starting point for uses in actual song.

In addition, The Urban Dictionary gives a [highly approved definition](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mymy) of *mymy* as

> the most outrageous, randomest , cutest chick ever. 
>   she may confuse you, but it can amaze you how she can always make you smile and forgive.
>
> *I'm sad, I need mymy.*

Comment: The Urban Dictionary entry quoted is irrelevant here. Even if it was relevant, when people write about names or people on UD, it's usually just someone's opinion and means nothing as far as actual connotations or meanings of the name goes.